# Seaborn doesn't recognize column names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

These are my first steps with seaborn: I am trying to use the lmplot method. [Here](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) there is an example that looks easy to understand, I report the some code without the "; sns.set(color_codes=True)" instruction at first line as it looks of marginal importance

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

Now I try to do the some with another dataFrame

```
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
a = 5
b = 3
rand = np.random.randn(len(x))
y = a + b*x + rand
xS = pd.Series(x)
yS = pd.Series(y)
data = pd.concat( [ xS, yS ], axis = 1)
g = sns.lmplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', data = data)
```

But the message of error looks weird to me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-41-20aa1710b84e>", line 1, in <module>
    g = sns.lmplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', data = data)

  File "C:\Users\fedel\Anaconda2c\lib\site-packages\seaborn\linearmodels.py", line 541, in lmplot
    data = data[cols]
```

Is there anyone who could help me with this issue?

Comment: dunno much about the murky world of numpy and pandas but seems like it doesnt know what `x` and `y` are. Perhaps you need to assign axes or names in the dataframe. Check [this](http://pastebin.com/5zkxmaFA) it launches and does something, no clue if it's what you want, but may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name pandas' series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
a = 5
b = 3
rand = np.random.randn(len(x))
y = a + b*x + rand
xS = pd.Series(x, name='x')
yS = pd.Series(y, name='y')
data = pd.concat( [ xS, yS ], axis = 1)
g = sns.lmplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', data = data)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was just an oversight. Here the code that works

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
a = 5
b = 3
rand = np.random.randn(len(x))
y = a + b*x + rand
xS = pd.Series(x)
yS = pd.Series(y)
d = pd.concat( [ xS, yS ], axis = 1)
d.columns = [ 'x axis', 'y axis']
g = sns.lmplot(x = 'x axis', y = 'y axis', data = d)
plt.show()
```